# Deleting current Position in a BST

Tags: c++, queue, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

Hello I currently both the working and not working solutions below for the problem
Given the root of a BINARY TREE:

Collect all the leaf nodes.
Remove all the leaf nodes.
Repeat until the tree is empty.

HOWEVER it only works when I go set the current->left || current->right to null if they are leaves
In my second example if I try to set current = NULL when it's a leaf node it doesn't update. Please help I will respond to any questions this is based on LEETCODE336

//NEED HELP ON THIS ONE NOT WORKING

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> findLeaves(TreeNode* root) {
         vector<vector<int>> result;
         if(root == NULL) return result;
 
        queue<TreeNode*> bfs;
       
        vector<int> leaves;
    
       while(root){
           
        bfs.push(root);
        while(!bfs.empty()){
            
        TreeNode* current = bfs.front();
        bfs.pop();
            
          
             if(current->left != nullptr) bfs.push(current->left);
             if(current->right != nullptr) bfs.push(current->right);
            
        
             if(current->left == nullptr && current->right == nullptr){
                leaves.push_back(current->val);
                 // NOT SETTING TO NULL WHEN IT'S A LEAF NODE
                 current = NULL;
             }              
        }
           result.push_back(leaves);
           leaves.clear();
    
           
        }
        return result;
        
    }
};
```

```
class Solution {
public:
bool isLeaf(TreeNode* current){
        
        if(current->left  == NULL && current->right == NULL) return true;
        else 
        return false;
        
    }
    vector<vector<int>> findLeaves(TreeNode* root) {
        
        
        vector<vector<int>> result;
        
        if(root == NULL) return result;
        
        queue<TreeNode*> bfs;
        
        vector<int> leaves;
        
       // bfs.push(root);
        
        
        while(root != NULL){
            if(isLeaf(root)){
                leaves.push_back(root->val);
                root = nullptr;
            }
            else {
                
                bfs.push(root);
            }
            
            
            while(!bfs.empty()){
                
                TreeNode* current = bfs.front();
                bfs.pop();
                
                
                if(current->left && isLeaf(current->left)){
                    leaves.push_back(current->left->val);
                    current->left = nullptr;
                }
                else if(current->left){
                    bfs.push(current->left);
                }
                
                
                 if(current->right && isLeaf(current->right)){
                    leaves.push_back(current->right->val);
                    current->right = nullptr;
                }
                else if(current->right){
                    bfs.push(current->right);
                }
                
                
            }
            result.push_back(leaves);
            leaves.clear();            
        }
        return result;
        
        
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see what is going on?

Comment: `current` is a local variable in the function. Assigning to it has no effect inside the tree – you need to modify the leaf's parent.

Comment: I'm really trying to understand still because if I modify the leaves parents to point to nullptr isn't current still local?                                                             if(current->left != NULL && isLeaf(current->left)){
                    leaves.push_back(current->left->val);
                    current->left = nullptr;
                }